# Installing very old versions with brew

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, homebrew, legacy-database

There is a really beautiful question written here: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula), however the solution is not working for me, I believe due to changes in brew.

I'm currently trying to install version 1.7.5 of elastic search onto my machine but am currently unable to.  It's not saved on my machine, and I'm thinking they removed brew versions since I cannot use it, and running

```
brew tap homebrew/boneyard
brew versions elasticsearch
```

throws an error saying `Error: Unknown command: version`.

I'm wondering what other options I have for installing elastic search 1.7.5, especially on brew, but at least so I can use it for my local setup (We need to upgrade the server, but first I need to get it running).

The version is also downloadable here https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-5 but I'm again unsure how to run it on my rails project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've come closer to a solution!  I think the best solution we'll get is to abandon brew and just run elasticsearch.

You can download the tar ball and then run ./elasticsearch inside the bin.

I found decent instructions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html

This said it's still not running with my rails site, however I think the issue may be something else as this point.  I'll edit this if I find a better solution.